# Take checkbox values and add them to text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text input that holds email addresses, each one gets separated by a `,` to indicate a breaking point for php.

```
<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control">
```

Rather than having to retype every email address every time, I have came up with a table that holds all my email addresses and allows me to select the ones I want to send emails to.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            Client
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php foreach($clients as $client): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="toList" name="to" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $client->name.' '.$client->last_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $client->email; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add">Add To Email</a>
```

Now, I just need to figure out a way, using javascript that when the `add` button is clicked javascript adds all the values of all the checked checkboxes to the `to` input field dividing each one by `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i have created a jsfiddle for you..

code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var checkedEmails = $("input[name=to]:checked").closest("tr");

        var data = [];
        $.each(checkedEmails, function() {
            data.push($.trim($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text()));

        });
        var str = data.join(",");
        $("#txt").val(str);
    });

});
```

working example:-

http://jsfiddle.net/XUjAH/1102/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your checkbox to look like this

```
<input id="toList<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="email-check-box" name="to" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $client->email;?>">
```

Javascript part

```
$(".add").on("click", function() {
   $('.email-check-box').each(function () {
       var current= (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
       if(current) {
           $(".form-control").val(
               $(".form-control").val() + current+ ","
           );
       }
   });
});
```